# Iphone 3G is very slow when launch apps that use GPS

Tags: iphone, gps

I have a iPhone 3G is very slow when launching apps that use GPS, like Google Maps or similar. The phone becomes unusable until I restart the OS.

One trick that seems to work occasionally is to deactivate the push notifications and then I can use the Google Maps without problems. Other days it also doesn't work and simply freezes.

How can I fix this?

My iPhone 3G is a 16GB article, running iOS 4.2.1, it is not jailbroken.

Comment: My wife has this exact same problem on iOS 4 with her 3G.

Answer (score 2):

Well I used to have an iPhone 3G and when I upgraded it to iOS 3 it was painfully slow. So what I did was this:

1) Switch off spotlight search (Or some elements of it) - Settings -> General -> Spotlight Search.

2) Reduce the amount of mail accounts being fetched to only the ones I needed to be fetched.

3) Try and keep minimal tabs open in Safari i.e. Don't leave all 8 open, keep closing them once you're finished.

4) Reset network settings at least once a month - i've found this also helps when you have no service, it just comes back instantly for me sometimes.

5) Try to use applications that are less resource intensive. This means stay clear of things like Infinity Blade.

6) Try to minimize how many calendars, contacts etc you have syncing.

7) Upgrade to iPhone 3GS/4/4S - they are all faster, the iPhone 3G has a slow processor.

I hope this helps. This really helped me speed my iPhone 3G and make certain applications usable a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption here is that when the GPS-enabled application initializes the GPS, it does not proceed until the GPS receives a "fix" (signal from 3 or more satellites).

Having never owned an iPhone 3G, I'm not sure what an appropriate amount of time for this to proceed is.  What you're experiencing *may* be normal.

Comment: the problem start with the upgrade of ios4. When the iphone has the ios3 never had any problem with gps

Comment: Have you called Apple or taken your phone to an Apple Store?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is completely shutting down your iPhone by holding the button on the top right end down until you see the slider bar, and then slide it.  Now turn it back on (same button).

This is the same as restarting your Mac, in that it cleans up the system a bit and reloads the OS (in this case, the iOS).

My wife has a 3g iPhone and I have the 4G.  This shutdown-restart does cure some ills.

Now you can re-try your process to see if the problem is cured.

You may have to connect to iTunes, backup, then Restore.  Read the iTunes Help menu to learn more about Restore.

Answer (score 0):

1. don't forget to do a hard reset.
   simply hold both the home button & the power button (top right) for about 7 seconds - (continue holding both buttons until the slider comes up * keep holding both until the screen goes black) - if done right the phone will do a clean reboot.
2. go to 'settings' then to 'location services' then turn off the location services for all the apps that are not high priority
3. dont forget to quit apps that are not in use & do steps 1-7 from tushar747